# Plot function line on scatter plot R

Tags: r, plot

I have a function

```
eq = function(x){x*2}
```

For which I would line to plot on a scatter plot in R.

My attempt is as follows (have not posted data, so this is not runnable,
but is syntacticly equivalent):

```
plot(per_class$input_kb, per_class$kb, col="red", ylab="Peak memory usage (kb)",
xlab="Input data (kb)", main="Peak memory per input size")
```

Which give me the plot. 
I then try

```
lines(eq,y=NULL)
```

However, I get the error.

```
Error in as.double(y) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
```

Is there a way to plot a function on a `plot` in R (ideally without ggplot2)?
Or do I have to make a data frame representing the function...seems kinda hacked.

Comment: I get an error with `lines` also. So edited to lines.

Comment: Yes exactly the same.

Comment: I tried with `lines` before posting actually. :) And ideas?

Comment: You need to feed your function, `eq`. Use something like `lines(per_class$input_kb, eq(per_class$input_kb))`, maybe. Or you can look into `curve` which is built specifically for plotting functions.

Comment: Oooooh, nice work! ;) That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Add as answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When plotting a function, you can either use `lines` or use `curve`.

The error is arising because `lines` requires vector (or matrix) arguments (type 'double' in the error message) and you are feeding it a function (type 'closure').

The `curve` function is designed for directly plotting functions and so may be preferable. below is an example of plotting two functions that estimate a set of points.

```
# get sample data
set.seed(1234)
x <- 1:20
y <- x^2 + 0.5 * x + 1 + rnorm(20)
y.est1 <- function(x) 1.1 * x^2 + 0.55 * x - 1
y.est2 <- function(x) .9 * x^2 + 0.45 * x + 2

# scatter plot
plot(x, y)
```

using `lines` to plot the first estimate in red.

```
lines(x, y.est1(x), col="red")
```

using `curve` to plot the second estimate in blue.

```
curve(y.est2, from=min(x), to=max(x), col="blue", add=TRUE)
```

For `curve` you need to include the add=TRUE argument, otherwise, `curve` will create a new plot.

This produces the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `abline()` helps.
As it is just adding a line to a plot.
In your case it should look like this, if I am not wrong:

```
abline(a=0, b=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned in the comments, lines() takes two arguments, both of which are values. You are sending in eq, a function, and y which is NULL. The error that you get is because NULL does not convert to a double.

You can try something like

```
x <- per_class$input_kb
line(x, eq(x))
```

Or simply

```
line(per_class$input_kb, eq(per_class$input_kb))
```